# Cannot use Citrix AppCenter to discover XenApp 6.5 farm

Tags: windows-server-2008, citrix, xenapp

I'm going through the initial configuration of Citrix XenApp 6.5. I have two servers, a DC and the XenApp server.

I created an OU XenApp, and a user "ctxadmin" on the DC. When configuring the XenApp farm I specific the admin user as DOMAIN\ctxadmin. Now when I'm logged in as **Administrator** and launch AppCenter, it says:

This user account is not an administrator of this farm, or there was a problem contacting the data store. Check that the data store server for the Citrix XenApp farm is online, and verify that your account is configured and enabled as an administrator on the farm.

If I log into the server as **ctxadmin** I cannot launch AppCenter without putting in the **Administrator** credentials, and then discovery doesn't work.

I seem to be in an endless loop. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. While logged in as the ctxadmin user, I went directly to the folder and launched the "cmi60" MMC file directly, not CmiLaunch.exe. This allowed me to run the app as the correct user and discover the farm.